# Jquery Mobile Fixed Header. Keep header at top

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a chat window, build using jquery mobile.

When the user clicks the text box, the virtual keyboard appears.  This pushes up the fixed footer, when you click "done", the keyboard slides down.  The header now appears in the middle of the page.

Is there a work around for this behavior?

Thanks a lot,
Dan

Comment: Have you tried adding a .refresh function to the call?

Comment: The following code doesn't work:

$('input').blur(function() {
   $('div[data-role="header"]').page();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT an intended way to do that, but I guess you can trigger `orientationchange` event or a `resize` event on `body` or `document` element. This should cause the interface to clean-up.

[edit]

This might be worth trying:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html

(It might be as good as fixed positioning for your app, who knows ;) )

Comment: If this isn't the intended way to do it, can you suggest a better way? i.e. what would you do in this situation?

Comment: You asked for a workaround. The better way to do that is to submit a bug in JQM, right? :) I would report a bug and try using fulscreen positioning in my app instead.

Comment: And I can't imagine how you would get to know when the keyboard is being hidden.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the best approach :) I think I'll try a different approach, though. iScroll seems to handle the fixed headers pretty well.  Thanks for the workarounds, I gave you cred. for the answer. Later man.